# The 'SubCatNewsID' property on 'SubCatNews' could not be set to a 'Boolean' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model

I'm getting this error some time, without any action I do

This appears at random

I use this frameworks:
Entity in CodeFirst type,Mvc3

Sometimes I get this erros in diffrent data types or for other models:

> The '**CatID**' property on '**Cat**' could not be set to a 'Boolean' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32

or

> The 'CatID' property on 'Cat' could not be set to a '**String**' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32

my site subject is news publishing and my client operators work with site and insert/edit data During all off day

Edit:
i see that this erros is not for a page,when i have this error,no page in my site not load and all of the pages have this message

my model:

```
public class SubCatNews
{
    [Key]
    public int SubCatNewsID { get; set; }
   // [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
   // public int? SubCatID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Details { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public bool? ImpStatus { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public bool? Visible { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public string pic { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public int? UsersID { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public int? StatusID { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public int? NewsTypeID { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public int? ZonesID { get; set; }
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public int? lanID { get; set; }
    //public int RatingSubCatNewsID { get; set; }



    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
   // public virtual SubCat SubCat { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsType NewsType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubCatNewsComment> SubCatNewsComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsInSubCat> NewsInSubCatss { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubNewsInTag> SubNewsInTags { get; set; }
    //public virtual RatingSubCatNews RatingSubCatNews { get; set; }
}
```

But i`m wondering that when i make any change in web.config,site is up!

i thing this is for caching data and values in Entity

my Context Creator:

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntityType, TIdType> : ContextGridController<HNewsPortalContext, TEntityType, TIdType>
    where TEntityType : class
{
    protected override HNewsPortalContext CreateContext()
    {
        return new HNewsPortalContext(); 
    }
}
```

before this time,my Context Creator,return Context like this:

```
HNewsPortalContext.Singleton;
```

i guess this was for static context and entity caching make this error,but newing context,do not fix my error

now when my site have this error,i make a little change(switch Custom Error Mode value between Off or RemoteOnly) in web.config and save it,then site is up

please help me
tanx

my full error message:
[full message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CObkb.jpg)
[full message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPCX.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i checked and see that was because overflowing my application pool
my site was on a shared server and session expire time was very long

finish

Answer (score 1):

Attach debugger, break on exception and check the stack trace to see what code is setting your properties.

Comment: i add my full error message image in first post,tanx,is that Enough?please explain this for me

Comment: You need to *debug* your code. If you don't know how to debug your code ask a co-worker for help.